# What is the exact function of an USB driver?

Tags: usb, microcontroller, pic

On reading many websites, I got confused.

Is the USB driver essential for making the device work? Or is it essential for making it communicate with the OS to do functions such as printing and doing other OS stuff?

---

To explain my question more clearly -
**I am working on developing a USB device, that will communicate with the software i will write.**

Do I need to develop a driver for such a system?
  ***or***
Do I just need the software program to send the proper messages to the device?

Comment: There are 2 USB drivers: one for the PIC and one for the machine connected to the PIC.  Which one are you confused about?

Comment: @cup Both! Do I need a driver for the pic?? Why? And the one the question states, if i have a program that communicates with the pic, do i still need a driver to make it work?

Comment: @cup one more question, do i need microchip usb framework to work with usb?? Or is it just a library for making the job easier?

Comment: You dont have to use their library you can create your own.  Microchips docs are usually full of holes so that will be a problem.  It in theory gets your job done faster if you dont have to re-write that code.

Comment: You can call these things drivers or not.  There is your software application then there is some amount of code between your application (part of your application perhaps or a library or in the kernel) whose job it is to communicate with usb in some form.  You can call that a driver, a library or just "my usb code".  Likewise on the MCU side, there is some amount of code that does the job of interfacing with the usb hardware, you can call it a driver or not, your choice, there is no global software police that is going to come down on you for using that term or not.

Comment: So you mean if i make a software program that communicates with the usb device using libusb library, this program is called a driver?

Comment: @user3407319  No that will be called class driver. class driver exactly knows how the device will behave. But it does not know low level things. For that it needs to use a low level driver and that is called USB stack which is USB driver + Host controller driver. USB driver is the interface between class driver and Host controller driver. Host controller driver is an interface between the hardware and the USB driver. Hope this made sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming your micro controller will be a USB device and your PC will be USB host.

The below diagram is the SW architecture for USB host. Now since your host is a PC, you do not need to worry about any part except the application at the top.

So lets talk about the device. What you need is a device stack which resembles with the host stack below. You can get the device stack easily and port it in your micro controller. But I suppose you need an application in your device too same as the top box of the below diagram which will understand the requests from the host and service the request.

[image]

So basically what I am saying that you need two applications and the rest of the components you can get it with some effort.

Regards.

Comment: What's the difference between class driver and usb driver? And do i need to implement both? And which of those layers i don't have to worry about and the pic will do for me? Thanks alot..

Comment: Class driver - Class driver knows how the device behaves. For example, If you connect USB drive, the class driver knows that what will be the descriptor structure of this device and how to communicated with a USB pen drive. Similarly a class driver for HID device knows how the HID device should behave.

Comment: USB driver - USB driver gives an easy interface to class driver developers to communicate with Host controller driver. Host controller driver APIs are not so straight forward. It has complex structures. But why bother class driver developers with so many details. So USB driver provides a simple API for class drivers to communicate.

Comment: For PIC, all of those layer should be available. Please try to search on the internet. I found http://www.signal11.us/oss/m-stack/ . 
I have not worked on PIC, but as you can see, the above link has details about the device stack as well as class driver. Also it is written that the class drivers are libusb complient. So your application can communicate using libusb apis. libusb APIs have documentations.